# Randomize player list with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app that displays a list of players in different sets.
Within each set I would like to display the list randomly each time.
I am using an ng-repeat, how can I randomize them?

Controller:
`$scope.players = ["p1", "p2"];`

Page:
`<dig ng-repeat="player in players">{{player}}<\div>`

Comment: upload some code please

Comment: possible duplicate of [shuffle array in ng-repeat angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789373/shuffle-array-in-ng-repeat-angular)

Comment: Using the math.random in a filter like that gives me an infinite digest error.