# AngularJS checkbox avoid counting when uncheck checkBox

Tags: angularjs

[Here is my running code in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AX051IiMsMD14AUBfMbr?p=preview)

I got a bug: When I uncheck the answer, I do not want to count how many times we select this answer? We will only count the number when we check the answer. For example, I check "Yes", I uncheck "Yes", I check "Yes" again, I will only show "Yes" was selected 2 times, instead of 3 times.

I read some posts about this issue, but cannot make it work by using checked property?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="answerSelected(ans)" ng-model="checkAnswer">{{ans.answer}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check like this,

```
  if (checkAnswer) {
      ans.count++;
      $scope.answerBoxSelected = true;
  }
```

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.questions = [{
      id: 1,
      question: "Do you like Foo?",
      answers: [{
        answer: "Yes",
        count: 0,
        id: 1,
        question_id: 1
      }, {
        answer: "No",
        count: 0,
        id: 2,
        question_id: 1
      }]
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      question: "Do you like Bar?",
      answers: [{
        answer: "Yes",
        count: 0,
        id: 1,
        question_id: 2
      }, {
        answer: "No",
        count: 0,
        id: 2,
        question_id: 2
      }]
    }
  ]

  $scope.question_index = 0;

  $scope.answerSelected = function(checkAnswer,ans) {
    if (checkAnswer) {
      ans.count++;
    }
     $scope.answerBoxSelected = true;
  };

  $scope.nextQuestion = function() {
    $scope.question_index++;
    $scope.answerBoxSelected = false;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="form-group" ng-if="question_index < questions.length">
      <div ng-repeat="item in questions">
        <div ng-if="question_index == $index">
          <h2>{{item.question}}</h2>
          <div ng-repeat="ans in item.answers">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-change="answerSelected(checkAnswer,ans)" ng-model="checkAnswer">{{ans.answer}}
            <br>
          </div>
          

          <div ng-if="answerBoxSelected" class="alert alert-warning">
            <h3>Answer Selection Summary</h3>
            <div ng-repeat="ans in item.answers">
              <p>
                "{{ans.answer}}" Has been selected {{ans.count}}
                <span ng-if="ans.count == 0">time</span>
                <span ng-if="ans.count > 0">times</span>
                <p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-if="answerBoxSelected && question_index < questions.length - 1" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next Question > </button>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="question_index == questions.length - 1 && answerBoxSelected">
      Congratulations! You answered all the questions. Good job!
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js">
 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look like this is not a good answer. Because if my answer is "I am good", so we may not hard code for that checking: if (checkAnswer.answer == 'Yes')

Comment: you do not have to hardcode just check the status true or false, check the demo

Comment: I can understand your solution better. Thanks. Are you also interested in this interesting challenge from me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916920/angularjs-randomly-show-data-bug

Answer (score 1):

change the ng-model to object property like `ng-model="ans.checkAnswer"`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="answerSelected(ans)" ng-model="ans.checkAnswer">{{ans.answer}}
```

Then change the function like this

```
$scope.answerSelected = function(checkAnswer) {
    if (checkAnswer.checkAnswer) {
        checkAnswer.count++;
    }
    $scope.answerBoxSelected = true;
};
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/oD4RLUUQGKrJzwNlkA9X?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function conditionally only when the checbox is checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="!checkAnswer || answerSelected(ans)" ng-model="checkAnswer">{{ans.answer}}
```

When the checkbox is checked, `checkAnswer` will evaluate to true, and the function will be called.

When the checkbox is unchecked, `checkAnswer` will evaluate to false, and the function will not be called.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HJL3zx5G1akGrsN4MaCt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to pass the element itself to the `answerSelected` method, and check its `checkAnswer` property. We will only increment the count if this property is `true`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="answerSelected(ans, this)" ng-model="checkAnswer">{{ans.answer}}

$scope.answerSelected = function(checkAnswer, elem) {
  if (elem.checkAnswer === true) {
    checkAnswer.count++;
  }

  $scope.answerBoxSelected = true;
};
```