# Randomize array in angular

Tags: angular

Is there any way to randomize array values in a `pipe` while doing a `*ngFor`? I have found that someone uses `ng-repeat` but I think it is for previous versions (I am using Angular 8.3).

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791049/12299366) answer but it is using JS. I would like to use only Angular features if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code from the link on your post on Typescript

```
shuffledArray:[]; 

shuffleArray(array) {
   var m = array.length, t, i;

   while (m) {    
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
   }

  return array;
}
```

Now you can call this shuffleArray method on method like

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.shuffledArray = this.shuffleArray(array) // add your array as input
}
```

On your HTML you can loop

```
<div *ngFor="let item of shuffledArray">
{{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'ts more compact use sort `this.array.sort((a,b)=>Math.random()<.5?-1:1)`

Comment: @Eliseo Do not use this method. It looks pretty, but isn't completely correct. Here are results after 10,000 iterations on how many times each number in your array hits index [0] (I can give the other results too): 1 = 29.19%, 2 = 29.53%, 3 = 20.06%, 4 = 11.91%, 5 = 5.99%, 6 = 3.32%

Comment: GREAT! sure I didn't know (and I hope don't forget never), thanks

Comment: @Eliseo We are all here to learn from each other!